# Reciving data from Cell counter through rs232

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I have a cell counter machine that sends data automatically after test end through a rs232 cable. I tried the following code to receive that data but I get nothing although I changed the `BaudRate` value many times. What is the problem?

My code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ComReadWrite
    Dim myPorts As Array
    Dim txtline As String
    Dim txtchar As String
    Dim txtbyte As String
    Dim txtexisting As String
    Delegate Sub setTextCallBack(ByVal txt As String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPorts = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        portnamecombo.Items.AddRange(myPorts)
        WriteButton.Enabled = False
        CloseButton.Enabled = False
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(110)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(300)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(600)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(1200)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(2400)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(4800)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(9600) 'Populate the baudratebox Combo box to common baud rates used 
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(14400)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(19200)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(38400)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(57600)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(115200)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(128000)
        BaudRateBox.Items.Add(256000)
        BaudRateBox.Text = 38400
    End Sub

    Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = portnamecombo.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = BaudRateBox.Text
        SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500

        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One

        SerialPort1.Open()

        Start.Enabled = False
        WriteButton.Enabled = True
        CloseButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub WriteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WriteButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write(Chr(6))
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        Start.Enabled = True
        WriteButton.Enabled = False
        CloseButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Try
            RecievedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub RecievedText(ByVal txt As String)
        If Me.ReadBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New setTextCallBack(AddressOf RecievedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(txt)})
        Else

            Me.ReadBox.Text &= txt
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How about trying RtsEanble and DtrEnable True settings? In addition, it will be easier to get answers if Cell counter programming materials are presented.

Comment: yes its true in  the cell counter system,i cannt get the system software

Comment: ooh.you mean in my serialport properties.no its false.i will try again by using the new settings to the serialport.thx friend

Comment: nothing change after changing that values to true

Comment: Then, please check if you can communicate with another port or PC running the terminal software instead of the cell counter, and check the usage/communication protocol/programming/etc. specifications of the cell counter. You may get an answer by adding the information in those specifications to the question.

Comment: thank you Kunif.is there any ready pogram can i use to send data from computer to my program to test it ?

Comment: There are many if you search. For example, [Serial Port Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Serial-Port-Sample-e8accf30), [Termite: a simple RS232 terminal](https://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm), [RealTerm: Serial/TCP Terminal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/)

Comment: yes  i tried termit and every thing  is going ok.i can send data to my program.then the problem in my cell counter although i tried all possible baudrate.thank you feind kunif

Comment: i get that data as atext how i convert it to chart